# zgrep not working on the AIX platform

Tags: linux, unix, aix

zgrep does not work in AIX and gives the following error

> ap61cp01> zgrep 9 ap_balance_bucket9_20120718.txt.gz
>   gzip: ap_balance_bucket9_20120718.txt.gz: Permission denied

Please let me know the solution !!!

Regards
Sumanth

Answer (score 1):

You have no permission to read the compressed file.

As root or ap_balance_bucket9_20120718.txt.gz owner, run

```
chmod a+r ap_balance_bucket9_20120718.txt.gz
```